# mysql query to compare timesheet entry between start time and end time

Tags: mysql, sql

The table is like :

```
Field 1 : employee_name
Field 2 : start_time
Field 3 : end_time
Field 4 : work_done
```

he will enter work done every day

```
RAM 10:10 10:40 coding
RAM 10:50 11:30 documentation
```

The requirement is there should not be any overlapping timesheet entry. Example: , RAM should not be allowed to enter again [say]10:20 or 11:10 in start_time or in end_time.

what is the query to find out whether RAM has entered for 10:20 or 11:10 either in start_time or in end_time.

Please help

Answer (score 2):

You can use this logic to get the overlaps for another interval

```
select t.*
from t
where @start_time < end_time and @end_time > start_time;
```

If this query returns no rows, then there are no overlaps.  You can also use `count(*)` to get the count of overlaps.

The variables `@start_time` and `@end_time` contain a new interval to check.

Note that it is not sufficient to use `between` to check the times, because `9:00-11:45` would also overlap, but neither end point is between times in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to allow the `end_time` of one interval to equal the `start_time` of the next interval?  If not, then the following will find all overlaps:

```
select
    x.employee_name,
    x.start_time as start_interval_1,
    x.end_time as end_interval_1,
    y.start_time as start_interval_2,
    y.end_time as end_interval_2
from
    timesheet as x
    inner join timesheet as y on x.employee_name = y.employee_name
where
    (x.start_time between y.start_time and y.end_time
    or x.end_time between y.start_time and y.end_time
    or y.start_time between x.start_time and x.end_time
    or y.end_time between x.start_time and x.end_time)
    and y.start_time >= x.start_time
    and not (y.start_time = x.start_time and y.end_time = x.end_time);
```

If you want to allow such endpoint overlaps, then the `between` clauses need to be replaced with clauses such as `x.start_time > y.start_time and x.start_time < y.end_time`.